# Getting the Select and Crop Functionality Using Custom Fields

Tags: images, uploads

I really like the WordPress' Twenty Seventeen theme's featured image upload where you can crop an image that with the set 2000x1200 dimensions. However, I haven't found a way to duplicate the feature for custom post types. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution where I can add a image crop uploader to the theme customization page. I have yet to figure out how to attach it to acf.

```
function add_my_media_controls($wp_customize) {

$wp_customize->add_section( 'theme_banner_image', array(
    'title'         => __( 'Banner Image', 'theme_banner_image' ),
    'priority'      => 35,
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting('banner_image', array(
'type' => 'theme_mod',
'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
'sanitize_callback' => 'absint'
));

$wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'banner_image', array(
    'section' => 'theme_banner_image',
    'label' => 'Banner Image',
    'width' => 2000,
    'height' => 1200
)));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'add_my_media_controls');
```